# Buffering problems with HTMLParser

Tags: python, html-parsing

I am working on a webbot that polls my university for the list of courses it has and so far, I have been able to get much done. But I am having trouble with the HTML parser. Heres the deal, when I get the list of courses for each major individually, the array of courses returned is correct. But when I do it in a for loop such as

```
for major in allMajors:
    dictionary[major] = GetAllCourses(major)
```

the problem is that the dictionary accumulates courses. So for instance `if allMajors == ['MajorA', 'MajorB']`, then MajorB will contain the courses of MajorA and MajorB. Here is my code.

```
def UIUCGetCourses(major, s):
    url = "https://ui2web1.apps.uillinois.edu/BANPROD1/bwskfcls.P_GetCrse"
    payload = {u'sel_instr': [u'dummy'], u'sel_camp': [u'dummy', u'dummy'], 
      ...
    }

    r = s.post(url=url, data=payload)

    p = UIUCcoursesParser()
    p.feed(r.content)
    p.close()

    return p.courses, s

class UIUCcoursesParser(HTMLParser):
    print_data = False
    courses = []
    descriptions = []
    internal_string = ""

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attr):
        if tag == 'td':
            for a in attr:                                  
                if a[0] == 'class' and a[1] == 'dddefault':
                    self.print_data = True

                if self.internal_string:
                    self.descriptions.append(self.internal_string)
                    self.internal_string = ""

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.print_data and data.isdigit():
            self.courses.append(data)
            self.print_data = False
        elif self.print_data:
            self.internal_string = self.internal_string + data.strip('\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I am an idiot! The problem is here:

```
class UIUCcoursesParser(HTMLParser):
    print_data = False
    courses = []
    descriptions = []
    internal_string = ""
```

These variables are class variables and not instance variables. http://legacy.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/acm-ws/sld051.htm

Comment: +1 "idiot" is a rather strong word for "newbie" but self-answers are good for SO.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're using class-scope data when you really want instance-scope:

```
class UIUCCoursesParse(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UIUCCoursesParser, self).__init__()
        self.print_data = False
        self.courses = []
        self.descriptions = []
        self.internal_string = ""
```

In your other class methods when you make references to `self` it is legal, but I don't think it is what you intend:

```
    def handle_starttag(...):
        ...
        self.descriptions.append(self.internal_string)
```

each of these apply to a single class-scope variable no matter how many parser instances you create.